# Dictionary<string, List <KeyValuePair<string,string>>>

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have created:

```
Dictionary<string, List <KeyValuePair<string,string>>> diction = new Dictionary<string, List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>>();
```

Later I've added to that list:

```
diction.Add(firststring, new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>());
diction[firststring].Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(1ststringlist, 2ndstringlist));
```

So now, If I want to read and show on screen this dictionary, how would I do it with foreach loop ? It's like 3 dimmension syntax, don't now how to create it and access it.

Also can anyone explain how to read this part?

```
diction[firststring].Add
```

What this marks [] excatly mean? I read whole dictionary there?

thank You for answer and Your time.

Comment: Is that all you want to do? Add `(string, string, string)` triplets to it and display them? Or is there a reason to use this complicated structure?

Comment: @RoyDictus Agreed... without knowing what you want to do we can provide an answer as below but there is likely a better way of accomplishing your goal if you provide more information.

Comment: no way that didn't answered before...

Comment: No offense, I think you should learn C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dictionaries store `key / value` pairs. In your case, your key type is `string` and value type is `List <KeyValuePair<string,string>>`.So when you do:

```
diction[firststring]
```

`firststring` is your `Key` and you are trying to access a `List <KeyValuePair<string,string>>`.Your best option is nested loops I think.if you want to display all values. For example:

```
foreach(var key in dict.Keys)
{
   // dict[key] returns List <KeyValuePair<string,string>>
   foreach(var value in dict[key])
   {
      // here type of value is  KeyValuePair<string,string>

      var currentValue = value.Value;
      var currentKey = value.Key;

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I think it did the job. However it's not showing any data for me but it might be someting wrong in my program earlier.

Answer (score 2):

For printing the datastructure, try this:

```
// string.Join(separator, enumerable) concatenates the enumerable together with 
// the separator string
var result = string.Join(
    Environment.NewLine,
    // on each line, we'll render key: {list}, using string.Join again to create a nice
    // string for the list value
    diction.Select(kvp => kvp.Key + ": " + string.Join(", ", kvp.Value)
);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

In general, to loop over the values of a dictionary, you can use foreach or LINQ just like with any IEnumerable data structure. IDictionary is an IEnumerable>, so the foreach variable will be of type KeyValuePair.

The syntax diction[key] allows you to get or set the value of the dictionary stored at the index key. It's similar to how array[i] lets you get or set the array value at index i. For example:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dict["a"] = 2;
Console.WriteLine(dict["a"]); // prints 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is store rows of 3 string values each, then the data structure you are using is far too complicated.

Here's a much simpler example, based on the `Tuple` class:

```
public class Triplet : Tuple<string, string, string>
{
    public Triplet(string item1, string item2, string item3) : base(item1, item2, item3)
    {
    }
}
```

So you just define a class `Triplet` that holds 3 strings, like above. Then you simply create a `List` of `Triplets` in your code:

```
// Your code here
var data = new List<Triplet>();

// Add rows
data.Add(new Triplet("John", "Paul", "George"));
data.Add(new Triplet("Gene", "Paul", "Ace"));

// Display
foreach(Triplet row in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", row.Item1, row.Item2, row.Item3);
}
```

and this is far simpler to read, understand, and maintain.

Comment: Hi, I need this formula cause I read excel file with 3 columns, assign each row of the column to this dictionary and I just want to check if I do it right by showing it on screen. I can't use static method as Yours cause number of rows and content is random...later I will need to randomize order of rows in 3rd column and export it to text file.